# Bootstrap datepicker beforeShowday works only on first change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, getjson

I'm trying to disable booked dates on datepicker. My code simply posts an ID to ajax.php file and i run a mysql query based on that id and get start and end dates. then i make an array that contains these dates and the ones in between. Finally I get this json_encoded array and it basically defines dates to be disabled on my bootstrap datepicker. I have recently found out that nothing is wrong with $.post method and changed the title. The problem was beforeShowday, it doesn't rerun after changes. Here is the jQuery code:

```
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate());
function getJsonRes(urlid){
var tarihler = [];
var url="ajax.php";
$.post( url, {"id":urlid}, function(data) { //this is the post request
$.each( data, function(key, val) {          //to retrieve json encoded data
   var tarih=val;
    tarihler.push(tarih);
});

var disabledDays = tarihler;
function daysDisabled(date) {
for (var i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
    if (new Date(disabledDays[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;

}

$('#grs').datepicker({ //this is start date
language:'tr',
todayHighlight:true,
weekStart: 1,
startDate:date,
autoclose: true,
format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
beforeShowDay: daysDisabled
})
   .on('changeDate', function (selected) {
    startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate(new Date(selected.date.valueOf()))+1);
    $('#cks').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
});

$('#cks').datepicker({ //this is end date
    todayHighlight:true,
    weekStart: 1,
    language:'tr',
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    beforeShowDay: daysDisabled
})
.on('changeDate', function (selected) {
    FromEndDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    FromEndDate.setDate(FromEndDate.getDate(new Date(selected.date.valueOf())));
    $('#grs').datepicker('setEndDate', FromEndDate);
});

}, "json");

}

$('#choice').change(function(){
var idvalue=$(this).val();
getJsonRes(idvalue);
});
```

Comment: The disabledDays array should change everytime I select a different option. But instead it works only first time. On next selections the disabledDays array stays the same. :( Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Moderator tip: Adding any additional information is best done by editing your post rather than adding a comment